# d3.js bar chart not updating with new information from csv

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I am trying to get my d3 bar graph to update with a csv and for some reason I keep getting the error that data is undefined when I run it with the live server extension, however I am not sure why because it works totally fine with a different csv. Earlier I was having a different error with this code where it would show up but only one bar would be filled in all the way to the top no matter what was selected from the dropdown. Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Here is my code:

```
        
        
           
            
            d3 Updating Bar Chart With Dropdown
            
        <style>

        input {
            position: relative;
            font-size: large;
            z-index: +1;
            padding: .5em;
            margin-bottom: .5em;
        }
        body {
            font: 14px sans-serif;
            background-color: lightgray;
        
        }
        select {
            display: block;
        }
        .bar {
            fill: rgb(209, 20, 184);
            fill-opacity: 0.7;
            stroke:rgb(0, 0, 0);
            stroke-width:2.5;   /* this changes the stroke width*/
            stroke-linecap:butt; 
            stroke-opacity: 1.0;
        }
        .axis path,
        .axis line {
            fill: none;
            stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            stroke-width:3;     /*again stroke width*/
            shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }
        </style>
    <h1>Bar Graph of Crashes by Light Condition</h1>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='vis-container'></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var fileName = "CSVs\TownTotalcrashesFatalsInjuryNoinjury.csv";    //Pulling Data
            var conditionFields = ["Crashes", "Fatals", "Injury", "No Injury"];
            d3.csv(fileName, function(error, data) {    //Error CheckingS
                var townMap = {};
                data.forEach(function(d) {
                    var town = d.Town;
                    townMap[town] = [];
                    conditionFields.forEach(function(field) {
                        townMap[town].push( +d[field] );
                    });
                });
                makeVis(townMap);
            });
            var makeVis = function(townMap) {
                var margin = { top: 30, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 50 },  //Dimensions of the           Visual
                    width  = 800 - margin.left - margin.right,
                    height = 400 - margin.top  - margin.bottom;
                var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()     //Getting Scale for Axis
                    .domain(conditionFields)
                    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.1);
                var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .range([height, 0]);
                var canvas = d3.select("#vis-container")    //Creating Canvas
                  .append("svg")
                    .attr("width",  width  + margin.left + margin.right)
                    .attr("height", height + margin.top  + margin.bottom)
                  .append("g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
                var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()   //Creation of X-Axis
                    .scale(xScale)
                    .orient("bottom");
                canvas.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "x axis")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                    .call(xAxis);
                var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()   //Creation of Y-axis
                    .scale(yScale)
                    .orient("left");
                var yAxisHandleForUpdate = canvas.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "y axis")
                    .call(yAxis);
                canvas.append("text")   //Addition of Axis Labels And Title 
                    .attr("transform",
                    "translate(" + (width/2) + " ," + 
                           (height + margin.top + 20) + ")")
                    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .text("Light Condition");
                canvas.append("text")
                    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                    .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
                    .attr("x",0 - (height / 2))
                    .attr("dy", "1em")
                    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .text("Crashes");
                canvas.append("text")
                    .attr("x", (width / 2))             
                    .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
                    .style("font-size", "18px")  
                var updateBars = function(data) {   //updating for new data
                    yScale.domain( d3.extent(data) );
                    yAxisHandleForUpdate.call(yAxis);
                    var bars = canvas.selectAll(".bar").data(data);
                    bars.enter()    // Add bars for new data
                      .append("rect")
                        .attr("class", "bar")
                        .attr("x", function(d,i) { return xScale( conditionFields[i] ); })
                        .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
                        .attr("y", function(d,i) { return yScale(d); })
                        .attr("height", function(d,i) { return height - yScale(d); });
                    bars    //updating new bars, removing old ones
                        .transition().duration(250)
                        .attr("y", function(d,i) { return yScale(d); })
                        .attr("height", function(d,i) { return height - yScale(d); });
                    bars.exit().remove();
                };
                var dropdownChange = function() {   //dropdown menu handler
                    var newTown = d3.select(this).property('value'),
                        newData   = townMap[newTown];
                    updateBars(newData);
                };
                var towns = Object.keys(townMap).sort();    //Creating Drop Down Menu
                var dropdown = d3.select("#vis-container")
                    .insert("select", "svg")
                    .on("change", dropdownChange);
                dropdown.selectAll("option")
                    .data(towns)
                  .enter().append("option")
                    .attr("value", function (d) { return d; })
                    .text(function (d) {
                        return d[0].toUpperCase() + d.slice(1,d.length); // capitalize 1st letter
                    });
                var initialData = townMap[ towns[0] ];
                updateBars(initialData);
            };
        </script>

        
       </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Which version of D3 you use? I don't see a call to merge (V4...) or update (V3)

Comment: I used v3, Im not sure why that got cut off in the code snip

Comment: I suggest to use the latest version (V6). Also, it might be useful to provide a snippet or a fiddle